# How to pass cookie from getIinitialprops to redux middleware in nextjs?

Tags: redux, next.js

I am getting cookie inside my `_app.jsx` but I am unable to send it to my custom API middleware.

So cookie needs to be there in the middleware but how tp pass it to middleware when its SSR. I have seen examples but they are not helping

I am using unfetch to call api in that middleware and I need token when user opens a page which supports SSR and I do all my api calls from middleware.

```
export default withRedux(initStore)(
  class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
      const cookie = nextCookie(ctx);
      return {
        pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
          ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
          : {}
      };
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @MarkJackson I stored it in redux. Or if you use axios then you can do global setup for it